# Pandas: Cumulative values of column to list [ without iteration ]

Tags: python, pandas

I'm searching for a fast way to fulfill following task:

Let's say I have following dataframe:

```
            value
index 
    1        'a'
    2        'b'
    3        'c'
    4        'd'
```

And I want to expand it to following dataframe:

```
            value    cum_value
index 
    1        'a'     []
    2        'b'     ['a']
    3        'c'     ['a', 'b']
    4        'd'     ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

What is the most performant way to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the column to a list of values and shift.  This causes the first element to become NaN, but we can use df.at to change this value to an empty list.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['a', 'bb', 'hi mom', 'this is a test'])

df[1] = df[0].apply(lambda x: [x]).shift()
df.at[0,1] = []
df[1] = df[1].cumsum()

print(df)
                0                1
0               a               []
1              bb              [a]
2          hi mom          [a, bb]
3  this is a test  [a, bb, hi mom]
```

Comment: `df[0].apply(list)` works as intended only if the column values are length-one iterables.

Comment: You could do a one liner using `df[1] = df[0].shift().fillna('').apply(lambda x: [x])`

Comment: Due to the fact, that I have to do this processing millions of times, and this method has been the fastest, I'll accept this answer. THX a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way to match your output adding one sep do not include in your string type columns

```
s = (df.value+'~').shift().fillna('').cumsum().str[:-1].str.split('~')
index
1           []
2          [a]
3       [a, b]
4    [a, b, c]
Name: value, dtype: object
df['New'] = s
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df['cum_value'] = df['value'].cumsum().apply(lambda char: [c for c in char]).shift()
df.at[0,'cum_value']=[]
```

EDIT - thanks for comment Jab:

```
df['cum_value'] = df['value'].cumsum().apply(list).shift()
df.at[0,'cum_value']=[]
```

Comment: You don’t need the `lambda` in apply, just literally put `list`. So should be `df['value'].cumsum().apply(list).shift()`

Comment: Yes, `[x for x in iterable]` is equivalent to `list(iterable)` therefore the builtin list function is much more efficient and readable than using a lambda.

Comment: This solution has more or less the same issue as I commented for (the earlier version of) [the answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57583099/10157759).

Comment: You're right. This does answer the OP, but for a more generalized approach manwithfewneeds's answer is better